# There is no option for me to connect to DSL network

Tags: internet

There is no option for me to choose the DSL network unless I delete the Cable network.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click on the DSL connection > Edit > General tab > tick "Automatically connect to this network when it is available" > Save

Comment: I don't want to connect to this connection automatically, I only connect to this when I need it.